# Solr Error: Archetypes Transaction note too large omitting 'searchwords'

Tags: plone

I'm running Solr 5.1.0 on our Plone 4.2.6 system.
Indexing works so far, yet I get the same error on my console every time I do so:

`2016-06-01 10:55:57 WARNING Archetypes Transaction note too large omitting 'searchwords' field missing value on instance '/path/to/document/or/image'; setting default value.`

I located the field `searchwords` in the collective.solr addon which we currently use. There it is used to elevate certain queries. Unfortunately I can't locate the exact line of code where this is used and where I can stop it from being used.

Can someone explain to me the way this collective.solr addon can be manipulated and or deactivated?

Answer (score 3):

First, the field `searchwords` is a important field in collective.solr. The field is used for query time boosting (make some specific content more important than others. Usually something like `searchwords:{value}^1000)` is stored in the default query.

**Now to the Warning:**
Archetypes tries to initialize the field `searchwords`, since it was missing on a object in your DB (It is new on schema, by at.schemaextender). This is a automated process and I'm pretty sure you don't wanna mess with Archetypes on this level ;-)

After setting the init value somewhere in [https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/e9ad0f4e76544b7890835ca93d25adeca4fc064f/Products/Archetypes/Schema/**init**.py#L491](https://github.com/plone/Products.Archetypes/blob/e9ad0f4e76544b7890835ca93d25adeca4fc064f/Products/Archetypes/Schema/__init__.py#L491) it extends the transaction node (This is what you see in the ZMI under `Undo` -> `manage_UndoForm`). The transaction note has a limited length of `65535` (Found this number in one of our packages --> https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.upgrade/commit/44efe457020f69ce00dff613252a090c291497c7, We fixed the same issues there and did some deep digging.)
It was fixed by implementing our own `TransacationNote`. This is probably not what you want.

BUT, I'm not sure if this is preventing you from actually committing to the DB?

**How to prevent `searchwords` from being used:**

This feature is hardcoded for Archetypes: Check https://github.com/collective/collective.solr/blob/master/src/collective/solr/extender.py#L20 so on reindexing it tries to access the field searchwords on all AT based content types.

First thing you can try is to remove the `searchwords` index from you solr config. For example in https://github.com/collective/collective.solr/blob/master/solr.cfg#L69

You need to remove the line..

`name:searchwords            type:string stored:true multivalued:true`

from your solr config.
Rebuild solr (You may delete the solr part) and reboot solr. Afterwards call `sorl-maintenance/reindex` on your plone root, it may no longer access this index (But I'm not sure what it does internally.)

If this doesn't help you need to modify the collective.solr itself (Remove the index and the field). Or even better make the two fields configurable and make a Feature PR on collective. solr :-)